# How to avoid deep nested callback?

Tags: meteor

In fact I do not how to write it because I have an array. here is sample code

```
rets = []
funcA(data[0], function(err, ret) {
  rets.push(ret)
    funcA(data[1], function(err, ret) {
      rets.push(ret)
        funcB(rets, function(err) {
        })
   })
})
```

because I don't know the size of `data`, so I cannot hardcode like above.

How can I do that? And even I can do that, it becomes deep nested callbacks which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use recursion instead of nested callbacks ?

Comment: can you explain/elaborate what you are trying to achieve in the function ?